# What is the mechanism for differentiating root requirements for terminal commands?

Tags: permissions, privileges

In the terminal, some operating system commands require root privileges and some don't.  What is the mechanism for controlling this?  Is each command actually a separate program with its own execution permissions or is there a table in Bash? (Am I correct that Bash is the command shell and the terminal is a user interface that passes it commands?)  I'm referring to operating system commands as opposed to running applications from the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes each applications typically has it's own permissions set via "permission bits" on the actual application. You can see these if you use the command `ls -l` on the various executables that you're trying to run.

```
$ ls -l /sbin/ | grep autrace
-rwxr-x---. 1 root root     15792 Aug 24 14:40 autrace
03:03:22-slm~ $ autrace
bash: /usr/sbin/autrace: Permission denied
```

But there are some commands where the "data" that they'll attempt to touch/access is what's restricted so looking at the permissions is not sufficient:

```
$ ls -l /sbin/ | grep "\bfdisk"
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    230512 Apr 25 05:19 fdisk
$ fdisk -l
$
```

Here the command executed as my userid, but that user does not have permissions to access the information about the physical disks on my system, and so `fdisk` shows me no output. If I elevate myself to root using `sudo` I can see the output as I intended:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l | head -10

Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5D1229E8-1234-1234-1234-ABCDEFG128790

Device           Start          End   Size Type
/dev/sda1         2048       411647   200M EFI System
```

#### Mechanisms that control this

There is no centralized control, all the control is decentralized and stored with the files as permissions bits on either the applications/executables (as I showed above), or on the data files that these tools will use, or on the directories where the files are contained.

#### Command shell

Your description isn't quite right with respect to Bash being a shell, and the terminal being a user interface that passes it commands. Rather the terminal is an application that is executed, and within it there's a shell running, typically Bash but it can be any number of shells.

*For example*

Here's the output of the `ps` command that shows how the processes for my current shell are structured:

```
$ ps axf | less
...
 8549 ?        Sl     0:08 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
 8552 ?        S      0:00  \_ gnome-pty-helper
10286 pts/13   Ss     0:00  \_ bash
12783 pts/13   Sl+    5:49  |   \_ vinagre
12868 pts/14   Ss     0:00  \_ bash
15742 pts/14   R+     0:00      \_ ps axf
15743 pts/14   S+     0:00      \_ less -r
```

Here you can see that my terminal, `gnome-terminal`, is running on top and it has child processes underneath it. These child processes are 2 `bash` shells where one of them is running an application called `vinagre` and another is running this `ps` command that I'm showing you here.

#### Additional restrictions

What I've described above is the foundation for how executables can be used by users on the system. But these are just the basics. Beyond these there are additional technologies such as ACL (Access Control Lists) and access control policies for the various exectuables.

ACLs are pretty straightforward, giving users outside of the traditional model of owner, group, and other, a more granular control.

Tools such as SELinux and AppArmor take this same approach but introduce at the Linux Kernel level the ability for rules to be put into place that restrict how application X can interact with the system as a whole. For example if you're running a Samba server, this application would need to be granted access to your filesystem outside of the normal areas that it would typically operate. You'd have to add extra policies to allow this.

*excerpt of SELinux man page*

> NSA  Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) is an implementation of a
>   flexible  mandatory access control architecture in the Linux operating
>   system.  The  SELinux architecture provides general support for the
>   enforcement of many kinds  of mandatory access control  policies, 
>   including those based on the concepts of  Type Enforcement®, Role-
>   Based Access Control, and Multi-Level Security.  Background
>   information and technical documentation about SELinux can be found at 
>   http://www.nsa.gov/research/selinux.

#### Command are part of what?

If you're confused whether a application is an actual file on the system, or if it's something else you can use the command `type` to determine this.

```
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin

$ type fdisk
fdisk is /usr/sbin/fdisk
```

So in the above examples, `pwd` is built into Bash, whereas `fdisk` is an actual file that resides at `/usr/sbin/fdisk`.

**NOTE:** For anything that's built-in, they're governed by the permissions of the Bash shell from which they're being invoked!

Comment: Thanks for the education and all of the clarification.  Great response.  Could you please clarify one more piece?  Are the operating system commands basically a collection of programs that operate as you described or is the code for all of them contained in Bash (or the kernel?), and there is a mechanism like an internal table or configuration file that defines which commands are root?

Comment: @fixer1234 - it depends on the command. In general most of the commands reside as files on the OSes harddrive. But some of the commands are called "built-ins" and are actually part of Bash itself. You can tell which ones are which with the command `type -a <cmd>`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the applications programs for the most part determine if root access is needed.  This is done usually in one of two ways: (1) an explicit check in the coding, or (2) use of files, directories, or other special files that require root access and would fail otherwise.

There is no central control of this at all.

Comment: Thanks.  I was referring to operating system commands as opposed to running applications from the terminal. (I edited the question just now to clarify).

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to prevent users to execute commands:

1. File permissions

   You can check them with `ls -l <file>`, in the form of something like "rwxr-xrw-", which defines the owner, group and other users' permissions to that file, being read, write and execution.
2. Access Control List

   If the mounted device has acl enabled you can get its properties with `getfacl` and check for the same permissions as above or a restriction for different users. An example:

   `[root]# getfacl <file>`

   > `# file: <file>`
   >
   > `# owner: <owner>`
   >
   > `# group: <group>`
   >
   > `user::rw-`
   >
   > `user:<different_user>:rwx`
   >
   > `group::r-`
   >
   > `mask::rwx`
   >
   > `other::r-`
3. The environment variables

   The PATH variable defines a list of directories where bash will look for commands. You can check its content with `echo $PATH`.
4. SElinux

   SElinux is another way of achieving this. You can check SElinux permits with `ls -Z <file>`.

These are just some examples, hope that helps.

Comment: There's also 5., the called program itself checks the current user, but I think that's more common in the "I refuse to be run as the superuser `root`" case.